# How can I reduce the error of SQL query in R?

Tags: r, sql-server

Here is my function

```
         getSQL <- function(server="server name", database="database name", Uid=" 
        user name", Pwd="password", Query){
        conlink <- paste('driver={SQL Server};server=', server,';database=',database,';Uid=', Uid, 
        ';Pwd=', Pwd,';Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False', sep="")
        conn <- odbcDriverConnect(conlink)
       dat <- sqlQuery(channel= conn, Query, stringsAsFactors = F)
       odbcCloseAll()
       return(dat)
           }
```

When I call the function using

```
  query.cut = "SELECT [measurename] 
       ,[OrgType]
     ,[year_session]
       ,[Star]
      ,[cutvalue]
      ,[Date]
      ,[File]
       FROM [database name].[dbo].[DST_Merged_Cutpoint]
       ORDER BY [year_session] DESC
          " 
        getSQL(Query=query.cut)
```

I get this error:

> Error in sqlQuery(conn, Query, stringsAsFactors = F) :
> first argument is not an open RODBC channel
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In odbcDriverConnect(conlink) :
> [RODBC] ERROR: state 28000, code 18456, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user ' insightm8'.
> 2: In odbcDriverConnect(conlink) :
> [RODBC] ERROR: state 01S00, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute
> 3: In odbcDriverConnect(conlink) :
> Error in sqlQuery(conn, Query, stringsAsFactors = F) :
> first argument is not an open RODBC channel

How can I fix these errors? Thanks in advance

Comment: I would first remove the space in `' insightm8'`

Comment: Great @Waldi, it works. But I just think about how much foolish I am!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care not to add spaces to `UID`:

> Server]Login failed for user ' insightm8'.

Reproducing this on an `SQL Server` connection creates the same error.

Try using `paste0` instead of `paste` :

```
conlink <- paste0('driver={SQL Server};server=', server,';database=',database,';Uid=', Uid, 
        ';Pwd=', Pwd,';Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False', sep="")
```